# GWT/Pyjamas canvas pixel manipulation

Tags: gwt, html, image-processing, canvas, pyjamas

I want to do some pixel level image manipulation for the HTML5 canvas through GWT or pyjamas. I know one way to do this in JavaScript is to use the contexts' createImageData() function to create an ImageData object, which lets you access pixel values. Is there an equivalent method for GWT/pyjamas? Also is there a performance difference between using this ImageData object and drawing 1x1 pixel size rectangles?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps: For GWT you can check out either one of these two libraries (not sure if they support ImageData):

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/GWTCanvas

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-canvas/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [JSNI](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html) to access any Javascript/HTML features not directly supported in GWT.